# Random number generator between two numbers - MatLab

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to create a random number generator between two numbers in MatLab but I am unable to figure out the correct equation.

I know that you can use the `rand()` function to create random numbers but what if I wanted to have numbers only generated between -.5 and .5? Is this possible to accomplish in MatLab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for adjusting the interval is listed in the help section on `rand()` :

Example 1

Generate values from the uniform distribution on the interval [a, b]:
`r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);`

Answer (score 3):

it is easy if you want get a random value between -.5~.5
here as an example

```
rand(1)-.5
```

more generally, to generate random value between [a b]
you can use a generator like this

```
rand(1）×（b-a)+a
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to do that is use

```
randi([min, max])
```